# How to get the name of the primary-key from a query

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am searching for a query that tell me the NAME of the primary-key of a table
example: In oracle I do this

> select CONSTRAINT_NAME from user_constraints where table_name = 'CT' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE ='P'

how to do that in sybase ?

Comment: You keep tagging questions ASE..that's not correct, the correct tag is [sybase-ase]  ASE on it's own is for Android Scripting Environment.

Comment: @MichaelGardner ah sorry for that, I will add sybase-ase instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select name     
from sysindexes
where indid > 0
and status2 & 2 = 2
```

Comment: Beautiful, it worked . Is it possible I have querry that determines if there the table has a primay key or no? exp: 
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('TRS') and xtype = PK.
( should i post my comment as another question ?)

Comment: I think yes it is possible and yes it's good idea create new question.